# Polyglossia with Vim-Latex and xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, vim-latex

I'm currently trying to get LaTeX working in Vim with Vim-LaTeX on Windows. LaTeX is working fine, however, I'm swedish and want to be able to show swedish characters such as å, ä and ö.

I've read about babel and such, but I haven't been able to get it working. I'm currently trying to use Xelatex with polyglossia instead. This is my current .tex file:

```
%        File: test.tex
%     Created: tor jan 26 09:00  2017 W EST
% Last Change: tor jan 26 09:00  2017 W EST
%
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sumlimits,]{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setdefaultlanguage[]{swedish}

\begin{document}
Förhoppningsvis fungerar det här.
\end{document}
```

As far as I understand it, this should work, and other variations and solutions to the problem that I've found hasn't worked for me. When compiled with the following command:

```
xelatex $*
```

It does compile to a PDF-file as expected, but this is the output:
[image]

Here is the log for xelatex outputs, notice the missing character error messages at the end:

```
    This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.1.26)  27 JAN 2017 15:21
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2016/06/28 v2.15d AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 199.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 297.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 394.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 397.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 518.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 634.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 635.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2739.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2740.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\polyglossia\polyglossia.sty"
Package: polyglossia 2015/03/25 v1.42.4 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and Lu
aLaTeX

(C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count99
)
(C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\makecmds\makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks19
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks20

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count100
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer (code)
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Bootstrap code
L3 Module: l3names 2016/10/13 v6722 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2016/09/01 v6696 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2016/08/19 v6684 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2016/09/07 v6700 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count101
\l_tmpa_int=\count102
\l_tmpb_int=\count103
\g_tmpa_int=\count104
\g_tmpb_int=\count105
L3 Module: l3quark 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count106
L3 Module: l3clist 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2016/09/01 v6695 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2016/08/19 v6691 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count107
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count108
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count109
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count110
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count111
L3 Module: l3skip 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen112
\c_max_dim=\dimen113
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen114
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen115
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen116
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen117
\c_zero_skip=\skip46
\c_max_skip=\skip47
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip48
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip49
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip50
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip51
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip11
\c_max_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip13
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip15
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip16
L3 Module: l3keys 2016/09/21 v6711 L3 Key-value interfaces
\l_keys_choice_int=\count112
L3 Module: l3fp 2016/11/21 v6761 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count113
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count114
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count115
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count116
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count117
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count118
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count119
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count120
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count121
L3 Module: l3box 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box28
\l_tmpa_box=\box29
\l_tmpb_box=\box30
\g_tmpa_box=\box31
\g_tmpb_box=\box32
L3 Module: l3coffins 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen124
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen127
L3 Module: l3color 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3sys 2015/09/25 v6087 L3 Experimental system/runtime functions
L3 Module: l3candidates 2016/08/19 v6688 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen128
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen129
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen130
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen131
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen132
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen133
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen134
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen135
\l__box_internal_box=\box42
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen136
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen137
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen138
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen139
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen140
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen141
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen142
L3 Module: l3luatex 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
)
(C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box43
))
(C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.
sty
Package: xparse 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count122
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count123
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count124
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count125
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count126
)
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
Package: fontspec-xetex 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count127
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count128
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count129
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen143
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen144
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen145
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def"
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 105.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane

(C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmss on input line 357
.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"
File: eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
\tipaTiiicode=\count130
\tipasavetokens=\toks21
\tipachecktokens=\toks22

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2016/07/11 v4.10 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (L3/RRM/
JK)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen146
\Gin@req@width=\dimen147
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__fontspec_post_arg:w with sig. 'mmO{}' on line 353.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'om' on line 355.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'om' on line 365.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'om' on line 375.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'om' on line 385.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 399.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 407.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'om' on line 415.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'om' on line 423.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mom' on line 437.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mom' on line 453.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 467.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 529.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 540.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 548.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 556.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 577.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 586.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 590.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 594.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 599.
.................................................
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count131

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 2705.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 2710.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 2715.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2720.
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count132
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count133
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 2736.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 2742.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 2746.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 2841.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 2845.
.................................................
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\xpg@normalclass=\XeTeXcharclass1
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\polyglossia\gloss-swedish.ldf"
File: gloss-swedish.ldf polyglossia: module for swedish
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is swedish.

(test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 12.
 (C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 12.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 13 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 13 replaced by U+FFFD.
Missing character: There is no � in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text!
Missing character: There is no � in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text!
[1

] (test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14719 strings out of 428408
 283964 string characters out of 3160621
 287705 words of memory out of 3000000
 18090 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3680 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 53i,4n,35p,10411b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this has nothing to do with polyglossia I think. Are you sure your source encoding is UTF-8? xelatex assumes it is.

Comment: You should be able to resolve this if you include a font with swedish characters, i.e. add `\usepackage{fontspec}` (this loads the CMU fonts)

Comment: @aehrm I've tried this and it made no difference. I'm updating the original question now with {fontspec} added as well as the log from xelatex.

Comment: I would guess that the warning "Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 13 replaced by U+FFFD." suggests your file is not saved with the UTF-8 encoding.  Have you tried saving the file in Notepad where you can see the encoding explicitly and then running xelatex on the command line.

Comment: @DaiBowen Yes, this seems to have been it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, xelatex expects a UTF-8 encoded file, as mentioned in the comments. Saving it as UTF-8 using another program such as notepad fixed the problem.

Comment: I copied the OP's code from my browser, and pasted it to a new blank text file. On my system, the new file is automatically UTF-8 (and UNIX line endings). The document compiled and showed all the Swedish characters. The font in use was LMRoman10-Regular. So, I believe that you are correct. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with the OP's document.